# Eclipse Galileo Java import cannot be resolve

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, eclipse-3.5

i imported project that alredy works using SVN in eclipse , i needed to gain knowledge about that one, but unfortunetly i can't even build it. Whenever i build it i get multiple errors that are caused by

```
The import XXX.bl.* cannot be resolved
```

There are around 20 imports but only the ones from XXX.bl.* dont work. I will type you what i already tried to do:

- Project -> Clean..
- Adding XXX.bl in build path
- Deleting and adding this imports
- Changing to Java 1.6
- Delete/Add JRE Library and adding Alternate JRE's
- Ticking in Project Facets Java and Utility Mode (for no reason i read somewhere about it)
- importing by clicking on "errored" viarable/class "import XXX.bl.*". Problem was solved but only until i Re-build/Clean project.
- Closing projects, cleaning, open projects, cleaning

The weirdest thing is that when i type XXX.bl. and then click CTRL + Space it actually autofill this imports with correct names.
Im using JDK (Java EE 6 SDK Update 1 (with JDK 6 U23)).
I spent alot of time in order to search for a fix but nothing helpt so i figure out meaby if i create question here by myself and inform you what i already did you will be able to help me somehow.

Sorry for my pretty bad english, and thanks in advance!

codes are in 'sync', imports are in XXX.bl

Comment: Please post the list of your project dependencies and the actual name of the imported package.

Comment: We also need to know the Eclipse project dependencies. This usually means that the jar containing all of the `pl.XXX.bl` packages didn't get added to the Eclipse project. (Using Maven/Ivy/Gradle prevents most of these problems.)

Comment: So everythink was added(like i said eclipse "sees" this packages in sync project, also sync has XXX.bl in java build path -> projects